# Storing and showing emojis in Android application using MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, emoji

I have an application talking to a NodeJS server via socket, that server is talking to PHP via HTTP, and that PHP is using MySQL.

When I try to insert Emojis in a text field, and save it to DB, when I get it back I see "?".

If I copy Emojis from wikipedia (for example `✒️ ❤️ ️ ️`) and force them to the DB, when I select them it shows `✒️ ❤️  ?️  ?️`

*Note:* The field in DB is `utf8mb4bin`.

- Why can't I store emojis directly from my device to DB?
- Why does some emojis show, while others don't?

*Note*: I also tried only PHP and MySQL, but with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.)Database :
Change Database default collection as **utf8mb4 ** .

2)Table :
Change Table collection as ** CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin **.

```
Query :                                                                                                                                                         

        ALTER TABLE Tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE 

utf8mb4_bin
```

3)Code :

```
insert into tablename (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7) values ('273','3','Hdhdhdhhzhzhzzhjzj 我爱你 ❌',49,1,'2016-09-13 08:02:29','2016-09-13 08:02:29')
```

4)Set utf8mb4 in database connection :

```
 $database_connection = new mysqli($server, $user,$password,$database_name); 
  $database_connection->set_charset("utf8mb4");
```